# how to get exception code in laravel5.5?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the exception code in Hanlder.php .  But i get the code , it is 0.

the code follow list ：

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception->getCode() >= 500) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'server error!'], '500');
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

I find the code in the exception , the  default value of code is 0.

```
public function __construct($message = "", $code = 0, $severity = 1, $filename = __FILE__, $lineno = __LINE__, $previous) { }
```

how can I get the code of exception?

And i am sorry ,my native language is chinese.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the exception is an instance of `HttpException`

```
// If this exception is an instance of HttpException 
if ($this->isHttpException($e)) { 
     // Grab the HTTP status code from the Exception 
     $status = $e->getStatusCode(); 
}
```

Comment: var_dump($this->isHttpException($e))); the result is false.    my exception class is 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError'.

Comment: You can provide a failover if it's not an httpexception, since in most cases it will be an error 500